# HttpError 403 when requesting admin.googleapis - Python Issue with Service Account

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-api, service-accounts, http-error

I'm writing a script in Python to try and pull data down from the Google Admin SDK API to get information on Google Groups & the users in those groups in GCP. I've been wracking my brain about this, and have been browsing NUMEROUS other Stack Overflow articles, documentation, videos - you name it, and nothing has worked so far.

**Some background:**

1. I am using a Service Account that has impersonation capabilities enabled. In theory, it should be impersonating an actual Google Admin user's account with limited access to only the things we need (e.g., Google Groups, Sheets and possibly Drive) to then be able to gain access to GCP resources. Recently, we also gave it domain delegation access, but limited to the following OAuth scopes in GCP (had to remove full URL because Stack Overflow was marking it as spam):

```
...admin.directory.user.readonly
...cloud-identity.groups.readonly OAuth
```

2. The Admin SDK API has already been enabled & a project has been created.
3. I am using the latest version of Python in VS Code with corresponding libraries installed.

**The Issue:
I receive the below error when I try to run my script - can someone help?**

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3 "/Users/username/Python Dev/mycoolenv/basiccsv.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Python Dev/mycoolenv/basiccsv.py", line 95, in <module>
    groups = admin_service.groups().list(domain=domain).execute()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?domain=exampledomain.com&alt=json returned "Not Authorized to access this resource/api". Details: "[{'message': 'Not Authorized to access this resource/api', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'forbidden'}]">
```

**My script for authentication is as follows, info redacted:**

```
from pathlib import Path
import googleapiclient.http
from googleapiclient.errors import (
    # BatchHttpRequest,
    # HttpMock,
    # HttpMockSequence,
    # HttpRequest,
    # MediaFileUpload,
    # MediaUpload,
    HttpError
)
import csv
import pickle
import google.auth
from google.auth import impersonated_credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from google.oauth2 import service_account
# from utils import googlesheets
# from google.oauth2.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Scope for API Connection
SCOPES = [...have several scopes listed here, but had to redact & can't include the full URL due to Stack Overflow's terms. The main scopes are...
...cloud-identity.groups.readonly
...admin.directory.user.readonly
...admin.directory.group
...admin.directory.user
...admin.directory.settings.basic
...admin.directory.user.security
...cloud-identity.groups
          ]


# GDrive Service Definition - below not in use at the moment
def get_gdrive_service():
    pass


# Impersonate the development Service Account using local credentials
source_credentials, _ = google.auth.default()
target_principal = "service_account_name.iam.serviceaccount.com"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(

)

gcp_credentials = google.auth.impersonated_credentials.Credentials(
    source_credentials=source_credentials,
    target_principal=target_principal,
    target_scopes=[],
    lifetime=3600
)

# ---The only users able to access the Admin SDK must be an Admin/Super admin of the Domain or a registered Google reseller. So, we must reference the admin who created the SA

# Groups Service Definition
def create_service():
    service_name = 'cloudidentity'
    api_version = 'v1'
    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        service_name,
        api_version,
        credentials=gcp_credentials
    )


# Google Drive API Service
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=gcp_credentials)
# service.close()

# Google Admin SDK API Service
admin_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
    'admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=gcp_credentials)

# Specify domain for which you want to retrieve groups
domain = 'exampledomain.com'

# Retrieve all groups for the specified domain
groups = admin_service.groups().list(domain=domain).execute()

# Iterate over the groups and print their details
try:
    for group in groups['groups']:
        group_id = group['id']
        group_name = group['name']
        group_email = group['email']
        print(f"Group ID: {group_id}")
        print(f"Group Name: {group_name}")
        print(f"Group Email: {group_email}")
        print("--------------------------")
except:
    print("No bueno")
```

**What I'm expecting:**
I'm expecting some type of message stating that the authentication was successful or at least an error once it gets up to the part where it tries to iterate through the Groups info via the Admin SDK API. However, it's getting stuck where the Service Account is apparently unable to communicate at all to our org's APIs.

**What I've tried:**

1. Tried changing the target_scopes=[] to:

```
    target_scopes=[
        SCOPES],
```

The above resulted in the below error, which is *slightly different:*

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups?domain=exampledomain.com&alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "[{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}]">
```

I also created a separate test file & writing the code completely different, but that didn't bear any fruit.

I've also tried commenting out all the additional import modules & scopes that don't pertain to the Admin SDK API, but nothing changed.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation to enable Domain Wide Delegation of Authority? The error message indicates you missed a step.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hi there! Thanks for the reply! Yes, I enabled Domain Wide Delegation of Authority, but only for the following scopes: admin.directory.user.readonly & cloud-identity.groups.readonly - do the OAuth scopes for the Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority need to match the additional scopes listed in the code (e.g. admin.directory.group.member, admin.directory.settings.basic, etc.)?

Comment: In setting up DWD, you must specify the scopes your application requires. You app cannot request scopes that are not listed.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks for that info! I'm now getting an error about a TypeError. 
username@FF91JP7VV0 github % /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 "/Users/username/Python Dev/mycoolenv/basiccsv.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Python Dev/mycoolenv/basiccsv.py", line 50, in <module>
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
TypeError: Credentials.from_service_account_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'

Not sure how I would resolve this? I'm no longer getting the 403 error when using this method

Comment: Please put details like that in your post. The missing parameter is the filename of the service account JSON key file. That is the file you downloaded from the Google Cloud web GUI when you created the service account.

Comment: @JohnHanley That error came up after granting additional OAuth scopes for the SA, however, we're not authorized to download keys locally. I guess a better question at this point would be: is there a better way I'm not considering to get the SA to impersonate a domain admin account via Python?

Comment: The filename parameter is not optional. I am not sure how your code could have worked previously. Double-check the code in your question and compare it with what you used previously. Implementing Domain Wide Delegation requires a service account.